# Why does a magnet not move in presence of an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

I only recently thought about this, and I can't come to any conclusion. An explanation for ferromagnets is perhaps explainable, and my teacher said Quantum Mechanics complicates things since the magnetic behavior is distorted, given for ferromagnets their origin is the spin of the electrons.

But what about materials that are magnets but are not ferromagnets, for whom the origin of magnetism is not *spin*?

Any of my reasonings is too vague for any explanation. If anyone can lead me to a source where I can read about this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Why do you think that "magnet does not move in presence of an electric field"? It surely can, if the electric field is non-uniform and strong enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The magnetic moments of the electrons are the building blocks of ferromagnets:

The magnetic moment of an atom is associated with the spins of the valence electrons. If we have a single valence electron, it's impossible to balance its spin. Therefore, atoms with a single valence electron (H, Li, Na, ...) posses the magnetic moment $\mu = \mu_B$. In contrast, a single iron atom possess six valence electron, from which five are pointing in one direction and one in the opposite direction. Thus, a single iron atom possesses a "strong (microscopic)" magnetic moment. Intuitively, we would argue that the magnetic moment of a single iron atom is $\mu = 4\mu_B$, however, due to "quantum mechanical effects" the value is closer to $4.9\mu_B$.

If we combining multiple iron atom the magnetic moments are preferably aligned parallel -- iron is a ferromagnet. Therefore, the magnetic moments of the individual  atoms add up and result in a macroscopic magnetic field.

#### Interaction between magnetic moment and electric field:

The magnetic potential energy is given by $U_{mag} = \mu \cdot B$, and a force can be describes by the "spatial change" of this potential energy -- which is just the inverted equation $dU_{mag} = F \cdot ds$. The "spatial change" is commonly written as $\nabla$ -- to emphasise that the "spatial change" depends on the direction in 3D, we write it as a vector  $\vec \nabla$. Thus, the inverse of the above equation is
$$\vec F = \frac{dU_{mag}}{ds} = \vec \nabla U_{mag} = \vec\nabla(\vec \mu \cdot \vec B)$$

From this relationship we see that in order to move the magnetic moment $\vec \mu$ we need a magnetic field $\vec B$.
Next, we use Maxwell's equations, which describe  the interaction between electric and magnetic  fields. They are
$$\vec\nabla\cdot\vec{E}= \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} \tag{1}$$
$$\vec\nabla\cdot\vec{B}=0 \tag{2}$$
$$\vec\nabla\times\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t} \tag{3}$$
$$\vec\nabla\times\vec{B}= \mu_0\vec\jmath+\mu_0\varepsilon_0\frac{\partial\vec{E}}{\partial t} \tag{4}$$
Only the third and forth relations mix $E$ and $B$ fields. However, they involve *time derivatives* -- the $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ means "change in time". Thus, if we **change** the electric field, we obtain a magnetic field, which acts upon the magnetic moment. Therefore, a **change** in the magnetic field can result in a motion of the magnet.  In contrast, if the electric field is constant, Maxwell's equations tell us that the magnetic field vanishes. Therefore, no force acts upon the magnetic moment, and thus no motion.

#### Combine the two parts:

In general a solid body is much more complicates than the individual atoms. However, this is not true for your question. For your question it is fine to consider the interaction between the electric field and the magnetic moments of the individual atoms.

Comment: I just see that you are a high school student. Let me simplify my answer

Comment: I like this bolded word:"change".This is the substance of the question.

Comment: @Semoi I can understand vector calculus, thanks!

Comment: It does make sense, and I feel ashamed I put aside Maxwell's equations before turning in my hypothesis, but there can be other effects of an electric field on a magnetic material right, like magnetic materials which have free electrons as the cause for their behavior might experience a voltage difference between two ends, and since the electrons will eventually stop moving, there should be a decrease in magnetic property? I suppose I have quite a bit of reading to do...

Comment: Sorry, but you lost me. I believed your question was about interaction between a magnet and an electric field. Now you talk about moving electric charges within the magnet. I honestly do not see the association with the question. Furthermore, using Maxwell's equations again, we know that a constant voltage difference does not affect the magnetic property.

Answer (score -2):

You are thinking of electromagnets.

This is such a complicated question!

It is because the EM tensor $F^{\alpha\beta} = \frac{dA^{\beta}}{dx_{a}}-\frac{dA^{a}}{dx_{\beta}}$ is always 0 in the interaction between a static electric field and a magnet.

Click [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity) for more information.

Comment: Can you lead me to an explanation for the ferromagnet case?

Comment: @SwagBeastSKJJ Hi!Have you understood my answer?You want to learn now how ferromagnetism is created?

Comment: I am not qualified to understand your answer since I am just a high schooler. I do understand that unbalanced spins of electrons cause ferromagnetism, I wanted to know why doesn't an electric field then cause a net force on the ferromagnet? Is it because the force on protons and electrons becomes completely balanced? That reasoning seems sound to me, but the confusion for me is about the materials for which the spins are balanced and they still exhibit magnetism.

Comment: You have heard that a moving charge generates magnetism and a moving magnet induces voltage but the key word is "moving" if the charge isnt moving and the magnet isnt moving then they cannot interact with each other.

Comment: The EM field tensor is definitely not zero anywhere here. There is a B field and an E field, which are entries in the EM field tensor. But you do say "in the interaction between" so what does that mean? "is always 0 in the interaction between a static electric field and a magnet." Also electromagnets too do not experience a force from an electric field. An electromagnet is just a magnet that uses currents to produce the magnetic field. There does not need to be any charged material. So they, for the same reason and just like permanent magnets, do not experience a force from an electric field.